# const параметр в копирующем конструкторе

Tags: c++, конструктор-копирования

В книге Б. Эккеля и в статьях пишут, что параметр в копирующем должен быть константным. Наверно так принято и действительно гарантия, что "источник" не будет изменен. но в этом случае мы ведь должны продублировать все методы на константные в случае если в теле копирующего мы хотим применить методы от "источника". Да , можно в копирующем сделать параметр не константный, но "по фасону" ли это ??? настораживает, что в книге говорится только, что параметр в копирующем должен быть объявлен только как const

Comment: Не просто `const`, а `const type&` :) Можно и не `const`, но потом-то ведь все равно придется переучиваться и методы - не изменяющие объект - сразу делать константными, а не потому, что иначе копирующий конструктор не работает... Хорошие привычки - использовать `const` везде, где можно - лучше приобретать сразу :)

Comment: @Harry  да понятно, что const type& иначе это не копирующий был бы. привычка, не спорю это хорошо, но у меня просто задача (там некий контейнер - хранилище байтиков) где надо прикрутить копирующие конструкторы . я стал делать. и , ой - а методы то все не константые в моем классе.

Comment: @Harry и что посоветуете ? ))

Comment: Если методы *не меняют* состояние класса - делать их константными. Если это невозможно - отдавать себе отчет, что ваше копирование *изменяет оригинал*, и убирать слово `const`...

Comment: @Harry отчет то я отдаю и "менять" источник не собираюсь в логике копирующего. Но мне непонятно, почему в книге не рассматривается копир. конструктор без константы... а в задаче требуется. в чем прикол то :))))

Comment: Никакого прикола. А вот если вы при копировании  изменяете копируемый объект, это уже прикол. Каждая функция должна заниматься тем, для чего она предназначена. Если  это копирование, значит  должна копировать в том числе и константные объекты. Точно также, если вы считаете количество некоторого объекта в последовательности,  не правильно по ходу изменять эту последовательность или состояние объектов этой последовательности, иначе  вы создадите хаос и не понятный интерфейс, что  легко запутает клиентам вашего класса и   будет являться источником многих логических ошибок.

Comment: В какой еще задаче?

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan да это ежу понятно, что в копире источник менять это безумие. Проблема в том, что класс описан в том числе и его методы и все эти методы не константные. А теперь просят реализовать копирующий конструктор. В идеале (по правилам хорошего тона) получается надо дублировать методы, так что ли?,чтобы копирующий все же принимал константный параметр.

Comment: Я не пойму причем тут методы. Если вы в конструкторе копирования вызываете какие то не константные методы,   значит вы все таки собираетесь менять копируемый объект.  А если вы имеете ввиду, что при копировании методы тоже копируются, то вы в заблуждениях. Если же методы не меняют состояние объекта, то они должны иметь конст квалификатор

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan я знаю , что методы не копируются , а только свойства. А класс написан до меня. его предназначение что-то вроде контейнера из байт . есть у него например функцию getSize() . она просто возвращает размер. чтобы я его использовал в копире надо его объявить как const . вот и скажите зачем я должен такие коррективы вносить в сущесвтующий класс ?

Answer (score 4):

Согласно стандарту языка C++ нешаблонный конструктор класса `X` является копирующим конструктором, если его первый параметр имеет тип `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` или `const volatile X&`, а остальные параметры отсутствуют или имеют значения по умолчанию.

Таким образом, если у вас нет подходящих неконстантных функций-членов для получения нужных данных, можете использовать `X&` (без `const`) и это всё равно будет копирующий конструктор. Но в таком случае вы не сможете, например, скопировать объект, являющийся константой.

С другой стороны, копирующий конструктор как и другие функции-члены класса всегда имеет доступ к приватным членам класса, поэтому можно обойтись вовсе без функций (не являющихся константными в том числе), чтобы скопировать состояние аргумента в новый создаваемый объект.